# How can i get distinct in MongoDB from subset of records not from the collection?

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I know & use this: (i'm using PHP)

```
$db->command(array('distinct' => 'cars', 'key' => 'manufacturer'));
```

But this gives me distinct car models in the whole collection.

What i want to do is specify for instance **Honda cars** and get their distinct models.

Something like:

```
$db->find(array('manifacturer' => 'Honda'))->distinct('model')
```

I unserstand that the syntax is wrong, but i cannot find any good way to do it. I have really big collection and after processing the data is a bad solution.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution so I will post it here:

```
$db->command(
    array(
        "distinct" => "cars",
        "key" => "model", 
        "query" => array("manufacturer" => "Honda")
    )
);
```

I hope someone find this usefull.